# One of my favourite flowers is tulips/a tulip/the tulip/tulip

Tags: articles, idiomatic-language, indefinite-article, zero-article

Which one is correct?

> One of my favourite flowers is **tulips/a tulip/the tulip/tulip**

Comment: _The tulip_. We use the definite article when making general statements about a particular species/variety of plant or animal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

... "the tulip".  This is a case for the "generic the".

Generally it is more common to use plurals for a generic *type*.

> Lions are big and fierce animals.

But it is possible to use "the" to mean the whole type:

> The lion is a big and fierce kind of animal.

In your "favourite" example we want a singular noun (because we say "One of...")
And the only possibility is to use "the tulip" to refer to the type.

However most speakers would probably turn this around:

> Tulips are one of my favourite flowers.

I don't know why for certain, but the singular/plural problem seems less bad in this order.

Comment: Thank you, James! Doesn't 'a tulip' work in this sentence?